# Как предотвратить выделение на странице

Tags: javascript, html, css

Добрый день. Как запретить выделение на странице.Если пользователь зажмёт мышь и потянет, то получается не очень красивый вид. Как это убрать?
Спасибо.

Comment: Кроссбраузерного или стопроцентно блокирующего решения нет.

Comment: ну хотя бы для хрома

Comment: это только раздражает, а если ваш текст надо скопипастить, то ничего не поможет.

Comment: Вы не сможете запретить выделение текста, user agent на то и user agent. Гораздо правильнее, красивее, честнее и выигрышнее будет написать хороший css, чтобы страница с выделенным текстом выглядела эстетично.

А то ваше текущее решение мне напоминает принцип «чем расставлять tabstop'ы, лучше запретим управление с клавиатуры».

Answer (score 1):

А ещё можно с помощью css

```
.no_select {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: Dazar, что-то оно всёравно выделяется.((( я кинул это в стили тех элементов, где не должно быть выделения

Comment: @Роман Ракзин, вон @Etki правильно написал, Кроссбраузерного или стопроцентно блокирующего решения нет.  
Я на своём сайте использовал, http://dazar.16mb.com/games/, внизу если на картинки кликнуть, галерея открывается, вот чтобы не выделялось, если много раз кликать на стрелочки. В хроме, опере, мозиле помогло. данные стили применены ко всему #gallery_wr.

Answer (score 0):

Запретите для необходимых элементов события OnMouseDown и OnSelectStart

```
<div onmousedown="return false" onselectstart="return false">
...content...
</div>
```

Comment: если поставил в самый главный элемент, то не выделяется всё(ок). Если ставлю в элемент где выделения не должно быть- он не выделяется(ок). 
Но если зажимаю на выделяемом элементе и тяну по "невыделяемому"- он выделяется. Что сэтим можно сделать?